# Why did it take Carlton the entire episode to realize he was a virgin?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-fresh-prince-of-bel-air

In the Fresh Prince episode *Mama's Baby, Carlton's Maybe* [(IMDb)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0583007/), Carlton's previous girlfriend shows up and claims that Carlton is the father of her child. By the end of the episode, in the chapel, Carlton explained that he couldn't possibly be the father, because he's a virgin.

Why did it take him almost the entire episode to realize that? If he had that realization at the beginning, there wouldn't have been an episode, but was there any other explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Cindy was, in Carlton’s own words:

> The love of my life, and Cindy is the woman I'm gonna spend the rest of my life with

And not his baby was just a nuisance that Carlton could overlook, because he also thought uncle Phil would give them money.

Also, him confiding to Will that he is still a virgin shows that he was really ashamed of that fact and having a baby is, well, ultimate proof of having sex.

Comment: I never had an issue with Carlton going along with it; but what always bugged me is why did Cindy show up claiming it was Carlton's baby? She also had to know that it wasn't his, and she couldn't have known that Carlton would simply be willing to go along with it. Her claiming it was Carlton's baby makes no sense.

Comment: @GendoIkari Cindy exactly knew that Carlton would go with it. Because she knew how Carlton felt about her. In modern days we would say that she put him in the friendzone wanting to use him as a lifebuoy.